# unable to put stack inside slivers. flutter

Tags: flutter, stack

My error is A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderStack.

```
Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        appbar(context),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://idsb.tmgrup.com.tr/ly/uploads/images/2020/05/13/35552.jpeg'))),
              height: createSize(347, context),
              width: createSize(375, context),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **SliverToBoxAdapter** widget to render any non sliver widget inside custom scroll view like this:

```
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        'https://idsb.tmgrup.com.tr/ly/uploads/images/2020/05/13/35552.jpeg'))),
                            height: createSize(347, context),
                            width: createSize(375, context),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SliverStack` inside the `CustomScrollView`, for that you need to use https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools this package

I share the example code

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverStack(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://idsb.tmgrup.com.tr/ly/uploads/images/2020/05/13/35552.jpeg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            height: 400,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```